# Press a button with postmessage

Tags: autohotkey

There is a way to make a mouse click with postmessage, a solution without moving the mouse (no click x, y)?

For example:

```
loop{   
      hotkey,ctrl,pressb
}
```

pressb:

```
msgbox a button

      PostMessage, 0x0201, , 9765141, ahk_class #32770

      PostMessage, 0x0202, , 9765141, ahk_class #32770

      ; or ControlClick, x95 y115, ahk_class #32770

return
```

Functions PostMessage and ControlClick don't work, the button is not pressed.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the app?  Believe it or not, it helps diagnosis these problems :-)  The WinSpy info would be useful too.

Comment: of course, this is the screenshot:

http://i50.tinypic.com/2na5y6r.jpg

Comment: Why don't you just use `controlclick` - it doesn't move your cursor.  You are trying to move a mountain.

Answer (score 0):

Each of these should work

- `ControlClick, Button1, ahk_class #32770`
- `ControlClick, OK, ahk_class #32770`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (until just recently). Most of the AutoHotKey interactive commands (such as SendMessage, ControlClick, SendRawMessage and so on) does not work within a 32700 window (a dialog) as well as other windows.

Solution: If you're running Windows 7. You need to run your AHK script as an administrator. To do this, right click on your AutoHotKey Script and click on 'Run as administrator'.